# Функция reorder() в R

Tags: r

Только начал изучать R и наткнулся на вот этот код.

```
dat <- us_contagious_diseases %>% filter(year == 1967 & disease=="Measles" & count>0 & !is.na(population)) %>%
mutate(rate = count / population * 10000 * 52 / weeks_reporting) %>%
mutate(state = reorder(state, rate))
```

Одно понять я не могу, как работает функция reorder? Интуитивно мне было ясно что в итоге столбцы state должны были быть отсортированы по значениям rate, но как бы я не проверял таблицу этого не происходило!

Однако после того как я создаю график:

```
dat %>% ggplot(aes(states, rate)) +
geom_bar(stat="identity") +
coord_flip()
```

Все чудесным образом сортируется. Скажите мне пожалуйста, по какому принципу это работает?

**Edit 1:**

Все же нашел кое-какой ответ на вопрос. Как оказалось сортируются не значения, а level-а по которым уже сортируется граф. Однако, мне все еще интересно какое же значение возвращает эта функция reorder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сами ответили - возвращает отсортированный результат применения функции к факторной переменной.

```
bymedian <- with(InsectSprays, reorder(spray, count, median))
```

Результат - сортировка spray по средним значениям count. Хотите просто по значениям - проще использовать arrange